# Optimize this function?

Tags: c++, v8

I have written this code (Uses V8 library). I went through it a couple of times and this feels like it's the only way I can write something like this. The aim of the function is to replace the JavaScript `.split()` function; as when using that function with a limit doesn't include the last part of the array in the returning array. EG:

```
var str = "Test split string with limit";
var out = str.split(' ', 2);
```

The array `out` will contain: [`Test`, `split`]. I want it to contain: [`Test`, `split`, `string with limit`].

I know there are pure JS ways to do this however I find them hacky and possibly slower(?) than a single C++ bind call.

Here's my function:

```
/**
 * Explodes a string but limits the tokens
 * @param input
 * @param delim
 * @param limit
 * @return
 */
void ASEngine::Engine::ASstrtok(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args)
{
    Assert(3, args);

    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    /* Get args */
    String::Utf8Value a1(args[0]);
    String::Utf8Value a2(args[1]);
    Local<Uint32> a3 = args[2]->ToUint32();

    std::string input  = std::string(*a1);
    std::string delim  = std::string(*a2);
    unsigned int limit = a3->Int32Value();

    unsigned int inputLen = input.length();

    // Declare a temporary array to shove into the return later
    std::vector<char*> tmp;
    tmp.reserve(limit);

    unsigned int delimlen = delim.length();
    char* cp = (char*) malloc(inputLen);
    char* cursor = cp + inputLen; // Cursor
    char* cpp = (char*) cp; // Keep the start of the string

    // Copy the haystack into a modifyable char ptr
    memset(cp + inputLen, 0x00, 1);
    memcpy(cp, input.c_str(), inputLen);

    unsigned int arrayIndex = 0;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        if((cursor = strstr(cp, delim.c_str())) == NULL)
        {
            cursor = (char*) cpp + inputLen;
            break;
        }

        for(int j=0;j<delimlen;j++)
            *(cursor+j) = 0x00;

        tmp.push_back(cp);

        cp = cursor + delimlen;
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    if(*(cp) != '\0')
    {
        arrayIndex++;
        tmp.push_back(cp);
    }

    Handle<Array> rtn = Array::New(args.GetIsolate(), arrayIndex);

    /* Loop through the temporary array and assign
       the variables to the V8 array */
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<arrayIndex;i++)
    {
        rtn->Set(i, String::NewFromUtf8(
            isolate, tmp[i], String::kNormalString, strlen(tmp[i])
        ));
    }

    /* Clean up memory */
    delete cpp;
    cp      = NULL;
    cpp     = NULL;
    cursor  = NULL;
    isolate = NULL;

    /* Set the return */
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(rtn);
}
```

If you are wondering: The variable `cpp` is there so I can delete the character pointer after I am done (As calling v8's `String::NewFromUtf8()` function copies the string) and I modify the `cp` pointer during the process of the function.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Optimise for what purpose? Make it faster? Make it smaller? Make it look neater?

Comment: To make it possibly faster. Neater or smaller is definitely not my first priority.

Answer (score 1):

Before optimising, I would fix the code so that it is correct.

```
char* cp = (char*) malloc(inputLen);
... 

/* Clean up memory */
delete cpp;
```

Whilst in some implementations, `new` and `malloc` do exactly the same thing, other implementations do not. So, if you allocate with `malloc`, use `free` to free the memory, not `delete`.

If you want to be clever about it, I expect:

```
tmp.reserve(limit+1);
```

will ensure that you have space for the remainder of the string without further allocation in the vector.

Since `cursor` isn't used after the loop, setting it inside the `if` that breaks the loop makes no sense.

```
    if((cursor = strstr(cp, delim.c_str())) == NULL)
    {
        cursor = (char*) cpp + inputLen;
        break;
    }
```

You are using casts to `(char *)` in places that don't need it, for example:

```
char* cpp = (char*) cp; // Keep the start of the string
```

(`cp` is a `char *` already).

This:

```
memset(cp + inputLen, 0x00, 1);
```

is the same as:

```
cp[inputlen] = 0;
```

but unless the compiler inlines the `memset`, much faster.

Likewsie:

```
*(cursor+j) = 0x00;
```

can be written:

```
cursor[j] = 0;
```

However, assuming `delimLen` is greater than 1, you could get away with:

```
    for(int j=0;j<delimlen;j++)
        *(cursor+j) = 0x00;
```

converted to:

```
  *cursor = 0;
```

Since your new `cp` value will skip to beyond `delimlen` anyway.

These serve absolutely no purpose:

```
cp      = NULL;
cpp     = NULL;
cursor  = NULL;
isolate = NULL;
```

Unfortunately, I expect most of the time in your function won't be in any of the code I've commented on. But in the passing arguments back and forth between the calling JS library and the native C++ code. I'd be surprised if you gain anything over writing the same code in JS. (None of the above make much of a difference when it comes to speed, it's just correctness and "a small number of potentially wasted cycles if the compiler is rather daft").

Comment: You are probably right in the fact that doing this in JS might be the same efficiency as writing a C++ bind. I was afraid you would mention the part where calling the v8 functions would be the slow down. Bummer. I will probably have to do a benchmark to be honest.

Comment: A benchmark is required before you start optimising anyway - guessing how much better something is would be pretty pointless.